# Angular2 component communication by shared singleton service

Tags: service, angular, singleton

I'm wondering how scopes are defined in `angular2`.
Currently I have an service `OrderService` with a property `CurrentOrder`.

I have two components `('order.component', 'clients.component')` acting as siblings instantiated by routing.

I provide OrderService in bootstrap and use it in both of my components by

```
import { OrderService} from './order.service';
```

and

```
constructor(private orderService:OrderService){ }
```

in ClientComponent i set CurrentOrder like `orderService.CurrentOrder=someNewOrder`.

after that I'm routing to OrderComponent and try to access `orderService.CurrentOrder` but its empty.

shouldn't orderService act as singleton provided in bootstrap ?

Comment: So you do a `bootstrap(App, [..., OrderService]` and in your components you don't have it in their respective providers array, right?

Comment: ah that was it.
I added it to bootstrap providers array and removed it from OrderComponent providers array but forgot to remove it from ClientComponet providers array.
Thanks a lot

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a shared service to be one instance only, don't put in the `providers` arrays of your components - only in the `bootstrap` call.